# How many ways of defining custom directive in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I've read about how can we define a custom directive and found the following method:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .directive("directiveName", function () {
        return {
            // implementation code will go here
        }
    });
```

but recently i found another way for defining the custom directive which is as follow:

```
angular.module("exampleApp", [])
    .directive("directiveName", function () {
        return function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // implementation code will go here
        }
    });
```

I'm interested to know that are which way is better and faster than the other? (Please describe pros and cons of both if possible) and are there any more ways to define custom directives?

Comment: The [manual](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives) says the best practice is to use the definition object rather than a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning a function in a directive is just a shorthand for the link function in the full definition.
So, if you are specifying something more than a link function then you need to write it the long way:

```
angular.module("myApp", []).
    directive("directiveName", function() {
        return {
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                // implementation code will go here
            },
            templateUrl: "template.html", // for example
        };
    })
;
```

Instead, if you just need the link function, you can use the *shortand* version:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .directive("directiveName", function() {
        return {
            // implementation code will go here
        }
    })
;
```